# Move Header Search to New Destination

Tags: magento2, blocks

Does anyone know the handle/block name for the header search? I'd like to move it.

Also, is there a reference anywhere online for all the default elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Magento 1.X

You will find catalogsearch.xml file over here.

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\layout
```

Catalog search folder keeps files regarding templates files.

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalogsearch
```

For Magento 2

If you r using magento 2 then check files in following path.

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\view\frontend\layout
vendor\magento\module-catalog-search\view\frontend\templates
```

Comment: @GarethDaine  welcome mate